# Eclipse needs to be restarted frequently for logcat to work properly

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adb, adt, logcat

As an Android developer, I am facing issue with [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) integration in Eclipse.
Most of the times, it works fine, but I sometimes have to restart Eclipse in order to have those useful log lines back. This occurs especially when I restart the test-dedicated handset.
Do you know if there's a way to make it work properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use `adb logcat` through the Windows command prompt.  You can get as many lines as you want using that.

Comment: Fair enough, i'll use the command line interface… It's a shame that ADT can't do it properly.

Comment: I know this is years old now, but just to add to what Haphazard shared:     open a CMD prompt or terminal, type: adb logcat {YOURTAG}:{D or V or whatever for the level} {ANOTHERTAG}:{D or V or whatever} *:s       (that last bit tells logcat to ignore anything other than your tags!)

Example:  adb logcat MyActivity:D SettingsFragment:D *:s

Answer (score 13):

Happens to me a lot, best tip i've been given is Window->Open Perspective->Other->DDMS.

Switch to this perspective, select your running instance in the Devices pane and Logcat starts showing output again.

Answer (score 3):

The command line version is probably the best way to use logcat.

Comment: I'll follow your advise :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems after restarting your device try highlighting it in the devices view and resetting adb as seen in the following image:

[image: Eclipse reset adb]

Comment: I am, it was there as far back as Froyo at least. Even so, from the command line adb kill-server && adb start-server would accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For me what works is to hit the [x] clear button to clear the logcat messages. In my case eclipse hanged because of the large number of logcat messages being displayed.